# Wagtail - migrate / copy data

Tags: django, wagtail

I have setup Wagtail on my project Dev server and some content has been added there, pages with streamfields and images. What is the best way to copy this data to the existing project on the live server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Database

On your dev server:

`./manage.py dumpdata > db.json`

Get that json file on to your live server and then:

`./manage.py loaddata db.json`

## Images

You should just be able to copy the files to the same relative location on the live server. The database does not store the files, just a reference to their filename.

Comment: Tried that and there were some conflicts, in the end had to delete the wagtail welcome page and edit the content_types IDs in the json dump and it seemed to work ok

Comment: @Dan Can you post the answer pleas?